# Execution failed for task ':device_info:extractDebugAnnotations'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I was trying to run the app on an Android device but I faced this exception. I also removed the package but the issue wasn't solved.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It solved. I think it was because I remove device_info folder in gradle cashe